# What capacitor should I use for DC decoupling a 50Ω transmission line?

Tags: capacitor, rf, impedance, decoupling-capacitor

I'm working with a chip using the 868MHz ISM band.

The chip has 50Ω termination on-die, a U.FL connector is to be placed right next to the RF output pin.
Since the antenna and the pigtail connecting the antenna to the U.FL connector are all 50Ω impedance, I shouldn't need an impedance matching circuit, given the distance between the IC RF out pin and the U.FL connector is about 5mm or less.

But I still want to ensure DC decoupling, and I like to have a confirmation on my approach figuring this out. The pigtail terminates at an SMA connector built into the box the RF module will be placed in.
The antenna is to be connected directly to that SMA connector. All connectors, the coax (RG-316) and the antenna are all 50Ω. All parts on the PCB (IC, cap, and U.FL connector) are SMDs.

Since I'm assuming 50Ω impedance on both sides of the capacitor, this is How I calculated the capacitance:
\begin{eqnarray*}
X_C &=& \frac{1}{2 \pi f C} \\
C &=& \frac{1}{2 \pi f C X_C} \\
&=& \frac{1}{2 \times \pi \times 868000000\operatorname{Hz} \times 50Ω} \\
&\approx& 3.6672 \times 10^{-12}\operatorname{F} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

So the capacitor should be a 3.6672pF cap, which is available as a 3.6pF cap in the E24 series or a 3.65pF cap in the E48 series.

Is my assumption correct?

The cap is primarily a safety measure, since it is not unlikely, someone might attach some sort of DC powered antenna amplifier to the SMA connector, and this could potentially feed back some of the DC power back into my device. To ensure the device doesn't get damage by this, I want to add the DC blocking cap, just to be sure.

Comment: No, you don't need a capacitor with 50 Ohm impedance at 868 MHz, you need a capacitor with an impedance much smaller than 50 Ohm. So something about 360 pF of the E6 or E12series.

Comment: You don't need to match the impedance of the cap to that of the transmission line.  You just want it to look like a short at your frequencies of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For series coupling of the signal / decoupling of the DC bias, you need a capacitor that disturbs the line as little as possible, so has an impedance << 50 Ω

You have already calculated the value that will give you 50 Ω as about 3.6 pF. Anything 100 pF or thereabouts should be OK.

There are a couple reasons you don't want to go too large.

- As the capacitor gets physically larger, the residual inductance increases, and its high frequency impedance rises. This should not be a problem at 1 GHz with small package ceramic SMDs in the 100 pF to 10 nF region. It might become a problem if you go significantly larger.
- A DC break can harden components behind them from ESD events, especially useful if you are connecting to an external thing like an antenna. The smaller the coupling capacitor, the less abuse it will let through.

If the ESD protection aspect is really important, then a better solution is to connect them with a highpass filter, which will use a capacitor closer to the 3.6 pF you calculated, together with a shunt L which matches it up for transmission, and also provides further protection.